# Is there any way to have a reoccurring appointment with a duration that lasts a week? (On Call Calendar)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

I have been trying to migrate from our team shared calendar in Exchange and move over to SharePoint 2010 for our permanent Team Calendar.  However, we have an On Call event that re-occurs and has a different user on call every week.  The duration is the entire week.  When attempting to put this in SharePoint, the option to set the duration to longer than 24 hours disappears.

Am I missing something here?  Can I create a custom list calendar and fix this?  This is the last thing that is keeping us from using SharePoint exclusively for our team calendar.

Comment: Very interesting question. So you want to create a recurring event that starts from Sunday morning and ends Saturday evening, and reoccurs every week?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Something that I can display in a calendar format for our IT department.

It re-occurs every few weeks, whenever the on call schedule rotates through all of our techs and comes back to the original person.  Each person is on call once ever 6 weeks or so.